# Logstash date format grok pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log file which has a date time in 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS' format. I am successful in parsing this with _ as delimiter and getting as 3 different text field in ES. But I need this to be converted as ISO_8601 so I can query and visualize the data by date or by hour or by minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specifically need ISO-8601, but care more about the events getting a queryable timestamp, [the `date` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) sounds like a better fit for you.

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "logdate", "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_SSS" ]
  }
}
```

This will set the `@timestamp` field to be a date-searchable field.

However, if you really do need Grok to do the work, you'll probably be best suited through using custom regexes.

```
(?<logyear>\d{4,})(?<logmonth>\d\d)(?<logday>\d\d)_(and so on)
```

This leverages single-digit captures to build your string.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply. +1 the date filter didnt suit the use case for me, but your custom regex did the work. awesome.

Comment: @Raj The date filter can target a field other than `@timestamp` if that fits your usecase better. It's the `target => "fieldname"` option.

Comment: Thanks @sysadmin1138. But after new "fieldname" added (as a timestamp) I am not able to figure out how I can hava a 'DataTable Graph' for number of logins by 'Customer number by a particular date by hour'.

Comment: What I am getting with custom regex

Customerlogin: wsname.
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 11: logdate.    
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  23: logHour.   ...22: logHour. 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   Customer.   Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   XXXXXXXXXX 5

Comment: what I am looking something like this. 

Customerlogin: wsname.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 11th Feb : logdate.    08th Feb: logdate.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  11PM: logHour.  10PM: logHour. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Customer.  Count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   XXXXXXXXXX 5

Comment: @Raj Your comments don't make any sense, and are format-stripped. Sounds like you're looking for a GROUP BY functionality of some kind, to provide counts of events per a bucket of time. When I need visualizations like that, I rely on the visualization tool to handle the bucketing; not ES. This is what Kibana and Grafana are designed for.

Comment: Sorry couldn't format the table above. Yes we do use kibana and as per the 'target' I added it to the timestamp field, thanks. With this, in kibana how do we see the number of logins per member per day? Also how to get this graph for a period of time like a month.